# Is there a way to "legally" eliminate TypeExtractor warnings in flink?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink

I changed my durations in profiling data I drag around all the flink data pipeline (*we are using flink 1.13*) from `Long` representation to `java.time.Duration`. Now my test output is littered with A LOT of

```
2022-11-07T23:34:46,247 INFO  TypeExtractor - class java.time.Duration does not contain a setter for field seconds
2022-11-07T23:34:46,247 INFO  TypeExtractor - Class class java.time.Duration cannot be used as a POJO type because not all fields are valid POJO fields, and must be processed as GenericType. Please read the Flink documentation on "Data Types & Serialization" for details of the effect on performance.
```

and a few similar warnings about `com.google.protobuf.ByteString`.
Google turned up few results on this, one of which suggested registering the non-POJO types as Kryo, so I tried `env.getConfig.registerKryoType(classOf[Duration])` but it didn't help.

I understand these `TypeExtractor` messages are trying to warn me about a potential performance hit, but I am not worried unless I understand how big it is, what I'm worried about is they are so plentiful it is hard to scroll up or down to meaningful logs, so I am tempted to just disable them in logger config.

Is there a way to *solve* them?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be resolved with what https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/types/ calls to use a `@DataTypeHint` annotation

> Data type hints can parameterize or replace the default extraction logic of individual function parameters and return types, structured classes, or fields of structured classes. An implementer can choose to what extent the default extraction logic should be modified by declaring a `@DataTypeHint` annotation.
>
> The `@DataTypeHint` annotation provides a set of optional hint parameters. Some of those parameters are shown in the following example. More information can be found in the documentation of the annotation class.